# Most maintainable way to handle hiding data from different roles MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

**Situation**:

Currently I'm working on a project at work that has about 13 controllers, all have Index, Summary(Table view that goes to index), Create, Details, Edit, and Delete views. Each of these controllers have their own ViewModels.

I recently joined the team and have changed this copy-paste project into a highly maintainable project with inheritance and interfaces.

**Problem**:

I just started working on the views creating HTML helpers and things of that sort to make the views more maintainable.

All of our controller actions are using the `[Authorize(Roles = "...")]` attribute.
The Index Views are in this style of setup (each list item makes use of each of the ViewModel's properties):

- Filter Section
- Table Header
- Table Contents
- Table Footer

Everyone else's initial thought was to just put `if (User.IsInRole(...))` in every spot applicable i.e. `if (User.IsInRole(...)) { @Html.DisplayFor(SomePropertyInFilterSection) }` and 3 more following the pattern `if (User.IsInRole(...)) { @Html.DisplayFor(SamePropertyInTableHeader) }`.
I think this is a massive clutter though and have started looking to make it cleaner (4 if statements to hide a 'single' piece of data seemed silly.
I think this is a massive clutter and there should be a much simpler way to have one single check for all of these if-statements (as they're checking the same thing but are in different locations).

**Options**:

The options that I see:

- 1. Do the if-statements in every place.
- 2. Have two separate views and check before leaving the controller.
- 3. Add css-classes to each piece of data and have a flag on the Master-ViewModel (this is the ViewModel all ViewModel's inherit from as they all share 2-3 properties) and have a JavaScript hide/remove those elements appropriately.

From my understanding security shouldn't be an issue since the data isn't sensitive (at the moment) and any links that might get clicked (maliciously or unintentionally) that shouldn't will have the `[Authorize]` attribute to fix that.

**Question**:

What would be the most maintainable way to achieve this?

The way I see my options above at the moment:

- 1. Way too full of clutter.
- 2. Solves the If-Statement clutter but adds an extra view that needs maintained and if one thing changes in one the other is probably going to need changed as well.
- 3. May become an issue if we decide to add sensitive data we do not wish those without correct authorization to see.

Are there any options that takes the best of both #2 and #3?

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by _`4 if statements to hide a 'single' piece of data seemed silly_`? Where would you need 4 `if` statements? Why would the controller pass data to the view which you then hide?

Comment: the 'single piece of data' being a property, that property is diaplayed 3-4 times on the index view (Filter, Table header, Table content, and table footer) each one of these locations needs an if-statement similar to the following `if (User.IsInRole(...)) { }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making some HTML-Helpers to aid this process.

```
public static MvcHtmlString IfRole(this MvcHtmlString content, HtmlHelper html, Role role)
{
    return html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(Roles.ToString(role)) ? content : MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Empty);
}
```

Which made all of these 4 line sections:

```
@if (User.IsInRole(Role.ToString(Role.MyRole))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(....)
}
```

One line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(....).IfRole(Html, Role.MyRole)
```

Additionally I came up with Helpers to abstract away as much content as possible (Buttons, Links, etc) so they all became one line. Some repeated 'control-like' html patterns became helpers as well.

The main thing that will help me is something I'm still considering. I was thinking of creating a function/interface on all ViewModels that returned a `Dictionary<String, Object>` of all its properties. Then have an HtmlHelper for Filter section, Table Header, etc. to use that data to contruct the data. (The reason I haven't done it and I'm only considering it is it would make unique looking pages a bit of work. Though I think in the end I'm going to do it and add optional `Dictionary<String, String>` parameter to add HtmlAttributes).

I hope this is helpful to someone in the future, it took me (unreasonably) a long while to come up with and I might not have came to this conclusion without *Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu's* thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a "right" answer. A lot of people will type in caps that you shouldn't even consider putting an if statement inside a view. However we need to remember that as professional developers we're getting paid for shipping products not following dogmas.

My suggestion would be use what's best on a case by case scenario for each view. Is the logic simple? have it inside a view. Does it start to clutter up? Make separate views. Is most of the logic in just one place? Make partial views. Doing this on a case by case scenario will also allow you to figure out what works best for your project.

However I would like to advise against having this logic JS or CSS based. It's not only about security, but you will also end up sending (sometimes a lot) of HTML just to have it hidden on browser. And when you will decide that your data is actually sensitive, there's a high change that you will not be able to secure it 100%.

Comment: I realized I did a not-so-great job explaining what I'm entirely asking so I edited the question. Your current answer doesn't entirely answer it but it was helpful (especially given that I did a poor job explaining, sorry about that).

Simple clarification: I'm not asking others directly what I should do in this situation, rather I'm asking if there's an option to remove the maintainability pitfalls of my #2 and #3 options (or if there are any other options available I'm not aware of).

Comment: I believe that my answer still stands. You avoid the pitfalls by not following a specific pattern for all views but instead apply the method which suits best each specific view.

Comment: They all fit the same exact pattern though which is why I'm asking the question. Two separate views makes me maintain double the views whereas adding a script to hide the data allows others to view data we might not want them to see. I was wondering if there were any options that aids either of these issues.